# Securing static html files cross domain

Tags: security, iis, webforms

I have multiple .NET projects that allow authenticated users to `browse html files` on `another domain` via `iframe`.

I'm struggling with `securing` these files so that no user can take the link from the iframe and share that link.

The projects are hosted on `iis`, and users are authenticated with a `JWT` token.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is unavailable to prevent user from getting link from your iframe because they are always able to view the link via developer tool.

But you could create a URL rewrite rule to strict the src link can only be accessed from your website by checking HTTP_REFERR header.

If the referrer domain incorrect or null, then your rule will block it.

Comment: It should be noted a user can choose to send whatever headers they want on their requests.

Comment: That's right. I think he also need more security policies like IP restriction or cookie verification to prevent this.